# how to download and install Jubler on ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04

I can't find a suitable version of jubler (subtitle editor) for Ubuntu 13.04 and Smplayer also.

Comment: 32bit or 64bit?

Answer (score 0):

SMPlayer it's already incluced in ubuntu repositories, so you can install it running this command: 
`sudo apt-get install smplayer`

or you can install it graphically using the "Ubuntu Software Center" searching for smplayer.

About jubler, you can download it from here: http://www.jubler.org/download.html

Comment: I know this link but there is no jubler version for Ubuntu 64 bit ., there is a version for 32 bit and it's not working on Ubuntu 64 bit. thanks

Comment: Generic Java version (if your system is not listed above)